# Does "visits" mean number of times or number of people?

Tags: meaning

> 500,000
>
> patient **visits** by 2020

It is a text in an infographic, and the position is exactly as above. The number is located above, and the rest is located below. I think "visits" mean number of times, but I want to be sure if there is any possibility that "visits" could mean "visitors". Is it "500,000 times of visit" or "500,000 visitors"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word is being used to explicitly mean "number of times".  It is likely that some patients made multiple visits. So the number of patients is likely to be less than 500000.